# How to append to a String and send through intents in Android?

Tags: java, android, string, android-intent

I am trying to add values to a string and then send it to the next activity. Here is the only relevant part of the code. `adding()` is the id of the button which appends values to the `String msg` and `sendMessage()` sends the msg altogether. When I just send a dummy value, the message is being passed, even when I add something like `1,2,3,4,5` at once instead of adding, it goes. But when I try to add, append and then send, it gives me an "Unfortunately stopped" error. 

I tried couple of tweaks, but still the same error. How to fix this?

```
public void adding(View view){
    EditText et1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    msg=msg+","+et1.getText().toString();
    TextView tv1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv1.setText(msg);

    et1.setText("");


}
public void sendMessage(View view){

    Intent intent=new Intent(this,Next.class);
    msg+=",";
    intent.putExtra("message", msg);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

EDIT: Activity Code-

```
package com.example.newlist;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    String msg="";
    int count=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void adding(View view){
        EditText et1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        msg=msg+","+et1.getText().toString();
        TextView tv1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv1.setText(msg);

        et1.setText("");


    }
    public void sendMessage(View view){

        Intent intent=new Intent(this,Next.class);
        msg+=",";
        intent.putExtra("message", msg);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    }
```

Comment: for each `adding()` call your are getting reference of `edittext` and `textview` better to get it in `onCreate()` method.

Comment: I have two buttons "adding" and "sendMessage" and one EditText box where I'm entering the values. If I keep it in onCreate(), the adding can't be done on clicking the "adding" button.

Comment: Nope, didn't. Do you mind posting your answer?

Comment: put your activity code

Comment: There you go, added the activity code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62843/discussion-between-rustam-and-kaushaya).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question correctly

1. move your findViewById to onCreate

   ```
   EditText et1;
   TextView tv1;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       et1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
       tv1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   }
   ```
2. in your adding method do it like this

   ```
   public void adding(View view){
       msg = msg + "," + et1.getText().toString();
       final String showMessage = msg;
       tv1.setText(showMessage);

       et1.setText("");
   }
   ```
3. in your sendMessage

   ```
   public void sendMessage(View view){
       Intent intent=new Intent(this,Next.class);
       msg+=",";
       final String msgThatWillSend = msg;
       intent.putExtra("message", msgThatWillSend);
       startActivity(intent);
   }
   ```

didn't test yet, but it should be work

Answer (score 0):

try this :

ActivityA.java

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity{

    StringBuilder msg=new StringBuilder();
    private EditText et1;
    private TextView tv1;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
        tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);


    }

    public void adding(View view){

        msg.append(" "+et1.getText().toString());

        tv1.setText(msg);

        et1.setText("");


    }
    public void sendMessage(View view){

        Intent intent=new Intent(this,Next.class);

        intent.putExtra("message", msg.toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Next.java

```
public class Next extends Activity{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.next);

        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        tv.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("message"));


    }

}
```

test.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"

>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:gravity="center"
  android:text=""
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et1"
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnadd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:onClick="adding"
    android:text="adding"

    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnsent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:text="SendMessage" />

</LinearLayout>
```

next.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

 >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="msg"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```